# Error connecting stripe api on laravel project Stripe\Exception\ApiConnectionException

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, stripe-payments

I have to connect Stripe api to my laravel project, but when starting the process i face this  error message: `Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 92]: HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1))`. I find on stackoverflow a guy with the same error and the answer was upgrading the TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2. I tried [here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/upgrade-your-php-integration-from-tls-1-0-to-tls-1-2) but nothing happened. Also i run the test for  reachability [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability), and in the end a disabled HTTP/2 before making any Stripe API calls as follows `$curl = new \Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient(); $curl->setEnableHttp2(false); \Stripe\ApiRequestor::setHttpClient($curl);`. Please i don't know what to do more.

checkout.js:

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_51H3t5vAzmeZmoL9jwK8YCeFMxvDnuC6FsV0Rg0XvMejoZziTbS6SMQlAIkOjLj68lGqkE57Yu46jF51zg6HrnyBK00Yg8Iyy45');

var $form = $('#checkout-form');

$form.submit(function(event) {
    $('#charge-error').addClass('hidden');
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken({
      number: $('#card-number').val(),
      cvc: $('#card-cvc').val(),
      exp_month: $('#card-expiry-month').val(),
      exp_year: $('#card-expiry-year').val(),
      name: $('#card-name').val()
    }, stripeResponseHandler);
    return false;
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) {
        $('#charge-error').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#charge-error').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disalbed', false);
    } else {// Token was created!

    // Get the token ID:
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

        // Submit the form:
        $form.get(0).submit();
    }
}
```

controller.php:

```
public function postCheckout(Request $request)
    {
        $curl = new \Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient();
        $curl->setEnableHttp2(false);
        \Stripe\ApiRequestor::setHttpClient($curl);

          //require_once("vendor/autoload.php");
          //require_once("/path/to/stripe-php/init.php");



        if (!Session::has('cart')) {
            return redirect()->route('shoppingCart');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);



        Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_?????
');
        try {
            Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => $cart->totalPrice * 100,
            "currency" => "usd",
            "source" => $request->input('stripeToken'), // obtained with Stripe.js
            "description" => "My First Test Charge"
        ));

       } catch (\Exeption $e) {
           return redirect()->route('checkout')->with('error', $e->getMessage());
       }

       Session::forget('cart');
       return redirect()->route('home')->with('succes', 'Successfully purchaised!');
    }

}
```

checkout.blade.php:

```
<span>
    <h4>Total (USD)</h4>
        </span>
          <strong>${{ $total }}</strong>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div id="charge-error" class="alert alert-danger {{ !Session::has('error') ? 'hidden' : '' }} "> {{ Session::get('error') }} 
    </div>
```

Comment: What version of Stripe-PHP are you using?

Comment: The version is `"stripe/stripe-php": "^7.40"`

Comment: Is your `controller.php` code there exactly correct?  How are you using `Charge` directly instead of using `\Stripe\Charge`?

Comment: yes i think is correct because on

Comment: Because on top of the file i have `use Stripe\Charge;
use Stripe\Stripe;
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research the solution was forcing  HTTP/1.1:

```
$curl = new \Stripe\HttpClient\CurlClient([CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1]);
$curl->setEnableHttp2(false);
\Stripe\ApiRequestor::setHttpClient($curl);
```